# Make current iteration repeat itself

Tags: javascript, loops

Is there a way to make the current iteration repeat itself in a loop?

```
var repeated = false;

var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    total += i;

    if (i == 33 && !repeated)
    {
        repeated = true;
        repeat; // imaginary
    }
}
```

Comment: well, i have to say if there was `C` language then you can use GOTO statement to use loop one more time. But still think somebody got something for you down there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just subtract 1 from `i` to "repeat"

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed No it won't because you set `repeated` to `true` and one of the conditions to repeat is `!repeated` (he said it would cause an infinite loop)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just subtract 1 from `i`.

```
var repeated = false;

var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    total += i;

    if (i == 33 && !repeated)
    {
        repeated = true;
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, don't need to repeat:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    total += i;
    if (i == 33)
    {
       total += i;
    }
}
```